# Jquery on keyup is not firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, keyup

I am using a asp.net web application and i have a script as following.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#popup input").keyup(function () {
        var total = 0;

        $(".txtLitAmount").each(function (index, item) {

            temp = parseFloat($(item).val());

            if (isNaN(temp))
                temp = 0
            total = total + temp;
        });
        $("#lblTotal").text(total);
    });
    });
</script>
```

Html part as.

```html
<div>   
<table width="100%" class="table">
         <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Dimension Code</th>
                        <th>Dimension Name</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

            <tr class="gradeX">

                <td>
                    Dubai Office</td>
                <td>
                    Sales</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="0.00" id="litAmount_0" class="txtLitAmount"></td>
            </tr>


            <tr class="gradeX">

                <td>
                    Dubai Office</td>
                <td>
                    Test</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="litAmount" type="text" value="0.00" id="litAmount_1" class="txtLitAmount"></td>
                
            </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
        <div style="width: 100%; padding-left: 624px;">
        <label style="margin-right: 20px;">SubTotal</label>
        <span id="lblTotal" class="lblSubtotal">0.00</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

When i run the above script on browser console, it is working.
But from application, it is not firing the key up event when type values in the textboxes. Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have just read your code, but you have no element/container with`id="popup"` :/

Answer (score 0):

I had checked your code i think you can follow my step.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input").keyup(function () {
    var total = 0;

    $(".txtLitAmount").each(function (index, item) {

        temp = parseFloat($(item).val());

        if (isNaN(temp))
            temp = 0
        total = total + temp;
    });
    $("#lblTotal").text(total);
});
});
```

Comment: No. Its not firing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have added this line in your code?

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes. I added this.

Answer (score 0):

It's running **https://www.bootply.com/QlIZUYOKDu**

I just changed `$("#popup input")` with `$(".txtLitAmount")`

Comment: For me its not working. I have added a break point on first line(_$("input").keyup(function () _).  Then at the time of page load control is coming to break point. But when type values on text box control is not coming to break point. Why this happening??

Comment: @Vahid any error message in the console? (right click anywhere on your web, select "inspect element", go to "console" tab)